# 'Fatal error: Out of memory' on Wordpress Cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, out-of-memory

I get these two errors on a cron script in Wordpress:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 767115264) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in wp-content/plugins/wp-crontrol/src/bootstrap.php(2228) : eval()'d code on line 154

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 767115264) (tried to allocate 69632 bytes) in wp-includes/functions.php on line 4830
```

The Cron script (set in plugin WP Crontrol) is for fetching products from an API and putting them in Woocommerce. The thing that I noticed is that this error occurs exactly after importing the first 15 products. This must mean that the 16th product is causing this. Maybe because it has a lot of data? I am unable to find out which product that is.

I have put this on top of the Cron script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

And I have set the following values in php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize=10240M;
post_max_size=20480M;
memory_limit=10240M;
```

And the folowing values in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '10240M' );
set_time_limit(0);
```

Why is this issue still occuring?

P.S. There are a couple thousand products to be fetched.

Comment: Depending on the environment on which your php runs, to increase the memory limit might be not the solution since the data you fetch is too big to handle nonetheless ...  try to find out, what data is actually fetched and you might get a clue whats the problem

Comment: “*A couple of thousands*” , maybe that’s your problem. Try to measure the size of the fetch

Comment: "Out of memory" rarely literally means that in my experience with PHP, unless you are below 256MB. The vast majority of time it is a runaway script. You should try to determine if it is "the sixteenth product", or "product #16". By that I mean is it always after 15 this happens, or does it happen because of a specific product after 15? You can test this by deleting #16 and seeing if the next product works.

Comment: @pierpy Its 2000 to be precise.

Comment: Is your cron script importing one product at a time, or trying to do a batch import?

Comment: @Caleb Batch import.

Comment: Reduce the number of products being imported in each run, and see if that changes the result.

Comment: Change the ordering of data response?